# I'm getting an error message but it exec fine?

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name
           FROM sys.tables
           WHERE name = 'Nums')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.Nums;
END

CREATE TABLE dbo.Nums
(
     number INT NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT PK_Nums PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(number ASC),
     code Char(9),
     date DATETIME
) ON [PRIMARY] 
    
INSERT INTO Nums (number, code, date)
VALUES (0, 485658235, '2000/01/01')

DECLARE @number int, @code Char(9), @date datetime

SET @number = (SELECT MAX (Number) FROM nums)
SET @date = (SELECT Date FROM Nums)
SET @code = (SELECT code FROM Nums)

WHILE @number < 100000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Nums--(number, code, date)
    VALUES (@number, @code, @date)

    SET @number = @number + 1
    SET @date = DATEADD(DAY, 5, @date)
    SET @code = LEFT(CAST(CAST(CEILING(RAND()* 10000000000) AS bigint) AS varchar),9) 
END

SELECT * FROM Nums
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 41
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Nums'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Nums'. The duplicate key value is (0)

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; what about the error don't you understand? Also, why are you using a `WHILE` is perform an insert row by agonising row? SQL is a set based language; a tally would be vastly faster than this.

Comment: Well - you have a first `INSERT` statement right after creating the table which inserts a row with `number = 0`. And then your `WHILE` loop selects that number, and **again** tries to insert the same value - that's **NOT** working - by design.$

Comment: This `485658235` is a numeric literal. Don't force the database engine to implicitly convert it for you - code like that is fragile and susceptible to error. The column named `Date` is defined as datetime - which contradicts the name. The value you insert is a date without time (using an unusual format - which is another problem). If you only want to store dates, then just use the DATE datatype. Don't encourage future data problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 1 to the number before the loop starts.

The error `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint` is not normally batch-aborting, therefore execution will continue with the next statement.

If you want to stop that, either force the batch to abort and rollback: `SET XACT_ABORT ON` (probably a good idea), or use `TRY/CATCH`.

I assume you also realize your procedure can be done in one statement, by joining a tally table or function (for example [these](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) by Itzik Ben-Gan), something like this:

```sql
INSERT @Nums (number, code, date)
SELECT
    t.Num,
    LEFT(CAST(CAST(CEILING(RAND()* 10000000000) AS bigint) AS varchar),9),
    '2000/01/01'
FROM fnTallyTable (0, 99999) t
```